# SQL Server Browser: Why is it disabled?

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to start SQL Server Browser through the SQL Server Configuration Manager.  However, not only is the "state" of SQL Server Browser `stopped`, but the options to `Start`, `Stop`, `Pause`, `Resume`, and `Restart` are all disabled (both in the right-click context menu, and through the Properties dialog).

(Also, in the Properties dialog, I have attempted all 3 options for "built-in account": Local System, Local Service, and Network Service.  I have also attempted "This Account" with various options.  In all cases, the functionality remains disabled.)

I initially thought it might be a port issue.  Apparently, SQL Server Browser uses Port 1434.  However, using a program called CurrPorts, I find that Port 1434 is not being used by any program.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The service itself is disabled by default. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, go to Properties -> Service tab -> Start Mode = Automatic.

Comment: You are on a *roll* today

Answer (score 2):

If it is disabled, go to Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services, and look for the SQL Server Agent. Right-click, and select "Properties." From the "Startup Type" dropdown, change from "Disabled" to "Automatic".

Comment: The OP is actually looking for the SQL Server Browser service rather than the Agent, but otherwise your suggestion may (or may not) help.